# Move Yii 1.x messages from file to db source

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently using default, file based Yii message source (CPhpMessageSource) and I wish to change it to DB based source (CDbMessageSource), but I already have tons of existing translations in file based source.

Is there a quick way to move those translations from file to db source?

Comment: I'd be interested to know this also, but I suspect there is not. Possibly you can create a script to read your translation file, store them as an array and explode to get the name and value, then insert to the db like this. But Yii seems to have everything so fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a [database migration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) in which you insert one row for each translation. If you need further help maybe try to share some code and I can try to provide you a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create script that reads all translations and inserts it into database:

```
$content = file_get_content($pathToMessages);
$translations = eval($content);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `translations` (`key`, `value`) VALUES ";
$params = [];
$inserts = [];
$index = 0;

foreach ($translations as $key => $value) {
   $inserts[] = "(:param{$index}, :param".($index + 1).")";
   $params[":param{$index}"] = $key;
   $params[":param".($index + 1)] = $value;
   $index += 2;
}

$sql .= implode(', ', $inserts);

// Convert it to Yii style.
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```